# node.js request encoding issue K�F�

Tags: node.js, request

```
request('https://xxxxx/api?param={"title": "你好", "number": "8"}',
    function(error, response, body){});
```

I use this API URL to send data (not getting), the data is like this in JSON format:
    {"title": "你好", "number": "8"}
, which contains some Chinese characters. The data is successfully sent to the "cloud". But I checked the data in that "cloud" and all Chinese characters become  "K�F�" these things.

I've tried using encoding: null and still doesn't work. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to escape the parameter first:

```
var qsescape = require('querystring').escape;

// ...

var param = qsescape('{"title": "你好", "number": "8"}');
request(`https://xxxxx/api?param=${param}`, ...)
```